# Migrating fails without any error

Tags: migrations, 8

I'm trying to run a migration D7 to D8 which I've coded. This is the command:

```
drush migrate-manifest manifest.yml --legacy-db-url=mysql://User:PASSW@localhost/drupal7ddbb --verbose
```

but basically no response, just something like done... but there is no nodes in the list of content.

Anyone knows how to make a deeper debug in Drupal8 migrations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your manifest.yml file and the migrations they reference.

Comment: Hi Ben,just added some code to clarify. Thank you.

Comment: The first thing i notice is that the migration id is progweb_custom_blog which isn't what you have in your yaml file.

Comment: ahm, true. Changed, runing and... no new content :-(

Comment: How far does it get? Any debug output? Make sure you wipe any existing migrate map tables that could have been left over from bad runs.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify 4 years later. At that point, migrate in core was not very stable. All those issues I was facing have gone away now, and migrate works really nice when moving from D7 or D6 to Drupal 8.

Answer (score 0):

A few things I see. `const JOIN = 'n.vid = nr.vid';` this is dead code. Not sure where it comes from but as far as I am aware there's nothing in `DrupalSqlBase` or `SqlBase` that uses the constant `JOIN`. I am not sure what this even wants to be.

Your process copies the `type` and then in the `destination` I think you try to set the type/bundle to article but that's simply not how this works. Everything under the destination key is passed to the destination plugin as configuration and the way we designed and implemented this system the destination plugins do not change a thing, they just import.

So:

```
source:
  plugin: progweb_custom_blog
  constants:
    type: article
process:
    type: constants/type
```

In your particular case, you could use a map similar to `und: en` to map blog to article but if you want article nodes then you must use either the constants or the map.